# My bot is staying online even after I've shut down all possible hosts

Tags: heroku, discord.js

Today I noticed that my bot was sending double messages (usually means that it's running 2 clients). After I shut down my bot from heroku, it was still online. Any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you are running the bot locally, and make sure all servers linked to the bot are turned off, sometimes the bot takes a while to completely shut down and go offline in discord, so try waiting for a few minutes.

in Heroku => navigate to resources tab and turn off `npm worker: start`

Comment: Thank you for your response! It turned out that somebody had leaked my key (note: I took measures to protect my key when I was developing the bot, but it still got leaked). I changed the key so now I should be ok.